# Printing formatted markdown text with Officedown knit_print_block

Tags: r-markdown, officer, officedown

I'm using the `officedown` function `knit_print_block` to print figure captions in Rmarkdown, with MS Word output. This is needed because I'm looping through lots of figures, and need each to return the captioned figure, as well as a cross-reference.

All's well with plain text. I can get the caption printed, and have a cross-reference object as well. However, if I try to use basic markdown formatting (in this case to superscript a value), such as `t/nmi^2^`, this does not return a superscript in the Word document. I have tried to return XML text as well (as documentation on`knit_print_block` states 'the function only print XML code') but do not return a superscripted value. Below is a minimal .Rmd example. It simply uses the mtcars dataset to make a meaningless plot, and then tries to return captions and bookmarks.

````
---
  output: officedown::rdocx_document
---
  
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(officedown)
library(officer)
library(ggplot2)

```

```{r, echo = FALSE, message=FALSE, warning=FALSE, fig.width= 7, fig.height= 4, results = 'asis'}

for (i in 1:2){
  
  #make a placeholder plot
  tmp_plot = ggplot(mtcars, aes(x = mpg , y = hp )) +
      geom_point()
    
  print(tmp_plot)
  
  #build the caption
  cap_text = paste0('Density (t/nmi^2^) in sample ', i)
  
  #build the bookmark 
  fig_name = paste0('samplesummary', i)
  
  #build the caption
  tmp_fig_caption = block_caption(cap_text,
                style =  'Normal',
                autonum = run_autonum(seq_id = 'fig',
                                      pre_label = "Figure ",
                                      bkm = fig_name))
  
  #print caption
  officedown::knit_print_block(tmp_fig_caption)
  
  
}

```

Just some normal text. Are cross-refernces returned? Yep: Figure\@ref(fig:samplesummary1), Figure \@ref(fig:samplesummary2)
````